# How to best manage JavaScript dependencies on a project with least hassle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I manage few JavaScript ReactJs projects. **Two of these projects are rarely updated**.

Last week, I updated and deployed these **two rarely updated projects** (after 14 months) with only two minor changes but the new build had several issues and caused a pain in testing and support.

I fear that yarn install resulted in updating several dependencies (although we have a yarn.lock file) and caused change in behaviour and added issues with it.

Now with this background, I wanted to ask experts here how do they manage their projects that are kept for a long time with no regular updates.

My **package.json** file looks like:-

```
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^1.0.5",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.7.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
```

Some example issues I faced: -

1) React Link router was not building correct link for URLs starting with `https://`. Found out it was a bug in the React dom version and used link starting with `://` to fix. 
BUT point is, this feature worked fine for years and broke in a recent build.

Do you use `~` or `^` or just bind to a specific version?

Thanks

Comment: to manage version controlling of the packages, manage lock files. `package-lock.json` for `npm`, and `yarn.lock` for `yarn`. also, remove `^` from version and then run `install`.

Comment: I do have `package-lock.json` but it is also updated when you run `yarn install`. Maybe binding to a specific version in `package.json` is the only solution. But just want to confirm if binding like this is an ok thing to do.

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly okay.